# How do you dye clear epoxy white?

Tags: epoxy

If you have perfectly clear epoxy casting resin, and you want to turn it white, what can you mix into the epoxy without it separating like oil and water?

Comment: Don't use paint. Use pigment

Comment: concrete supply places have pigments that are used to color concrete.  I've used solomon pigments and davis color pigments.  I think there are liquid ones but I've just used the dust form.

Comment: This is a cross-site duplicate of [*Giving epoxy resin an opaque color*](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/11214/319) at crafts.se, where I suggested TiO₂ powder, and [*Are there every-day substances that can be used to color 2-component epoxy adhesive?*](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/11428/319) where I suggested (and tested) baking soda.  Other suggestions included talc, chalk, and various  paints, the latter with mixed results

Answer (score 1):

Fumed Silica Microbaloons happen to have that effect, though they are mostly used to thicken (and lighten) epoxy. Likewise acrylic microballoons. **Not** the phenolic ones, those are dark brown.